# I want to learn PL/SQL 

Tags: oracle, plsql

Please suggest some Freeware both for Client and server side. This is to learn every thing about PL/SQL..

Comment: Freeware for what? To look at the code (you'll need open source, not just freeware)? To play with (how are you expecting that to help you learn?).

Comment: How come you have added mysql as tag? Removed.

Comment: I am totally new to computers so couldnt know the differences

Answer (score 13):

You can use [Oracle XE](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/xe/index.html) database and [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html). Both are free.
Add a good book on PL/SQL. I'd suggest [Steven's book.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596514468) 

Oracle products can be used for learning for free.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle 11g Enterprise and Standard Edition come with a development licence that allows the use of either for free for educational purposes.

Download from here: http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/index.html.

Try [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/sql/index.html) for writing PL/SQL with. This provides syntax support and compilation error reporting.